# Excel - use a formula to generate cell reference within a formula

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have a table of data - basically with suppliers names along the top, work types down the side and the margins we make from using each supplier to deliver the work type.

On a seperate sheet I want the user to be able to type or select a work type and it to deliver the supplier which gives the maximum margin for the work type and the associated margin.

I have used the following margin and it gives me the right answer

```
=INDEX('Master SOR YR5'!CT8:GA8,MATCH(MAX('Master SOR YR5'!CT12:GA12),'Master SOR YR5'!CT12:GA12,0))&" - "&ROUND(INDEX('Master SOR YR5'!CT12:GA12,MATCH(MAX('Master SOR YR5'!CT12:GA12),'Master SOR YR5'!CT12:GA12,0)),4)*100&"%"
```

However, this is limited to one worktype in row 12. Depending on what work type is entered, the row reference will obviously change - how can I make it work? I was thinking of somehow replacing the `12` with a `vlookup` which returns the row number `=(VLOOKUP(B7,'Master SOR YR5'!A12:D100000,4)*1+11)`

But I can't see how to embed the `vlookup` within the `Index` formula and get to to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You would replace your range in the MATCH with another INDEX/MATCH.

Replace all

```
'Master SOR YR5'!CT12:GA12
```

With

```
INDEX('Master SOR YR5'!CT:GA,MATCH(B7,'Master SOR YR5'!A:A,0),0)
```

This will return the proper row to the formula for further disection.